# Y Axis and value on top of bars

Tags: pentaho-cde

How to show the y-axis and values in top of each bars using pentaho cde charts.

PFA.
[image]

Comment: You want the above data to be stacked ?

Comment: No ,, I just need the y -axis values on top of bar .. UI should look same as above attachment,.